# One-line to import module using relative path

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module called in a code the following way:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
import preprocessor
```

Is there a way to make into one line?

I tried this but failed:

```
from .. import preprocessor
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: from ..preprocessor import *

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in the project directory?

Comment: @XiaoqiChu: No. It's just plain one Python code **preprocessor.py**.

Comment: @Serjik: I got same error message.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you cannot circumvent the PYTHONPATH, so the answer is no you can't do that, you need either sys.path.append() or have set PYTHONPATH already

Comment: Please could you update question for Python version. I would assume if using relative imports you are trying to write a python 2.7x module?

Comment: @neversaint Please let me know if my answer was helpful to you?

Answer (score 2):

You should run it as package

This is my fie structure:

```
/test
   /path1
     __init__.py
     preprocessor.py
     /path2
         __init__.py
         prog1.py
```

preprocessor.py:

```
a = 12
```

prog1.py:

```
from ..preprocessor import a 
print a
```

command line:

```
 test$   python -m path1.path2.prog1
```

output:

```
 12
```